# How can I identify what package an AttributeError: 'module' is referring to?

Tags: python, pyramid

I am trying to move a Python pyramid app that I'm writing from one server to another.  I checked the code out from source control and ran a `python setup.py develop` to prepare the environment, but when I try to run `pserve development.ini` I get the following traceback:

```
2013-02-27 20:38:20,269 INFO  [pyramid_scss][MainThread] adding asset path /home/pgrace/repos/Asterisk-WebApps/Cedar-Root/opt/cedar/cedar/assets/scss
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/bin/pserve", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pyramid==1.4', 'console_scripts', 'pserve')()
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 50, in main
    return command.run()
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 304, in run
    global_conf=vars)
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/scripts/pserve.py", line 328, in loadapp
    return loadapp(app_spec, name=name, relative_to=relative_to, **kw)
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 247, in loadapp
    return loadobj(APP, uri, name=name, **kw)
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 272, in loadobj
    return context.create()
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 710, in create
    return self.object_type.invoke(self)
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 146, in invoke
    return fix_call(context.object, context.global_conf, **context.local_conf)
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/paste/deploy/util.py", line 56, in fix_call
    val = callable(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/pgrace/repos/Asterisk-WebApps/Cedar-Root/opt/cedar/cedar/__init__.py", line 18, in main
    config.include("pyramid_scss")
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 773, in include
    c(configurator)
  File "/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_scss/__init__.py", line 88, in includeme
    scss.LOAD_PATHS = ','.join([scss.LOAD_PATHS, ','.join(load_paths)])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LOAD_PATHS'
```

Now, I can tell that the problem originates in pyramid_scss, but as far as I can tell the code it references is  fine, it's as if the `module` class does not contain the LOAD_PATHS directive.  I'm trying to figure out which module it's referring to so that I can track down if I'm missing a dependency or something. Does anyone have any ideas how I'd go about identifying where the `module` reference is pointing to so I can check that code?

EDIT:
The error comes in the `includeme` definition which from what I've read is automatically included every time a pyramid-specific package is ...instantiated?  Maybe?  At any rate, it's saying that scss.LOAD_PATHS does not exist, yes, but there's no scss class in either `pyramid_scss` or `pyScss` packages, leading me to wonder if there's some other class that's being late-bound or something.

```
def includeme(config):
    load_paths, static_path = _get_import_paths(config.registry.settings)
    scss.LOAD_PATHS = ','.join([scss.LOAD_PATHS, ','.join(load_paths)])
    scss.STATIC_ROOT = static_path
    config.add_renderer('scss', renderer_factory)
```

The `Scss` class in pyScss does include a LOAD_PATHS directive but I don't see where the object scss is bound to a Scss class definition.  I'm wondering whether there's something missing in the `def includeme` from above that might be part of the answer, but then it begs the question -- this worked right on the other machine, why break now?  There's something else missing that I'm just not picking up on.

Comment: `/home/pgrace/venvs/pyramid/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pyramid_scss/` ? It looks like scss from within here is the one throwing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From examining the code for the `scss` package, it looks like the `LOAD_PATHS` global variable might have been moved from `__init__.py` to `config.py`.

Thus, if you want to try to fix the `pyramid_scss` app, you could change line 88 of `pyramid_scss/__init__.py` to read:

```
scss.config.LOAD_PATHS = ','.join([scss.config.LOAD_PATHS, ','.join(load_paths)])
```

Comment: Thank you a hundred times over!  That moved things along.  It sounds like someone needs to update the pyramid_scss project.  I'll see if I can do a pull request, unless you'd like to do it.

Comment: @PeterGrace: Ah, just saw your [pull request](https://github.com/jessedhillon/pyramid_scss/pull/7)- great.

Comment: yeah, I wanted to get it done before I forgot about it and went on to other things.  Hopefully he'll accept it, it seems like the project might be dead.

Answer (score 2):

The one-but-last line tells you *which* module is affected:

```
    scss.LOAD_PATHS = ','.join([scss.LOAD_PATHS, ','.join(load_paths)])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LOAD_PATHS'
```

So the `scss` module has no `LOAD_PATHS` attribute.